# That that vs That what vs What vs That

Tags: difference

Are all the four correct grammatically and in usage? Any difference?

- That that I have told you is a secret.
- That what I have told you is a secret.
- What I have told you is a secret.
- That I have told you is a secret.

I mean to say that the thing I said to you is a secret.

Comment: First, there are four...  "Correct" in what sense? What do you want them to mean? Please, we need to get a bit more explanation in this sort of question. Knowing that they're "correct" or not is irrelevant if we don't know what you're trying to say. "That I have told you is a secret" **is** perfectly acceptable but it doesn't mean the same thing as the others. What do you actually want to say?

Comment: In theory, the first two are syntactically valid, but in practice they're completely non-idiomatic, so no-one would use them. And as @Catija says, the last one means something completely different *(**The fact that** I told you is a secret)*.

Comment: ...also note [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=What+I+have+told+you%2CWhat+I+told+you&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CWhat%20I%20have%20told%20you%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CWhat%20I%20told%20you%3B%2Cc0) showing that native speakers increasingly avoid pointlessly complex Present Perfect constructions where they aren't necessary. *What I told you is a secret* - no ***have*** is required.

Comment: Better grammar would be *that which I have told you is a secret*.

Comment: @Majenko Why is it better?

Comment: You are referring to just one thing, the secret thing. http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/8309/18020

Comment: @Majenko It seems you don't understand the difference between what and which.

Comment: 43 years natively speaking English I think I know *which* to use...

Comment: @Majenko I have never heard of such usage.

Comment: @SovereignSun Surely you have... I point it out in my answer... so at the very least, unless you haven't read my answer yet, you've seen it once before.

Comment: (That item) (to which I am referring) (is secret)

Comment: @Catija I saw that in ypur answer but I still never met it. Which only refers to a choice, I cannot see any here. That's what I know.

Comment: Which does not *only* refer to a choice... It may *usually*... as I said already... there are no absolutes in English.

Comment: @Sovereign Sun I  notice  you didn't even bother with me.  I am so glad you have never "met it". You mean, of course,: you have never run into it. Actually, Majenko is 100% accurate. In older English, one does see: That which I have imparted to you is secret. For example. But never: that that. What an idea.

Comment: There are no absolutes in English? Are there no absolutes in any language?? Let's not confuse two things: speakers speak how they speak and the more power to them. But, when one is not a native speaker and looking to understand standard forms, there are things one must learn first. Now, if you just want to learn street English or southern English or Black English, that's fine. But even those dialects of English have standard rules that can be linguistically described. And, one has to state ***that that*** is the dialect one is interested in.

Comment: In my  previous post, /that that/ is used correctly and grammatically, introducing a relative clause followed by a demonstrative pronoun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have four sentences that are variants using "that" and "what". Some are correct, some are incorrect and some just don't mean what you want them to mean.

So, let's start with what you want to say:

> I mean to say that the thing i said to you is a secret.

The simplest way of putting it is the third option

> What I have told you is a secret.

This would be the standard form that most people would use.

---

> That that I have told you is a secret.

This sounds Shakespearean. It means what you want it to mean but you'd be hard pressed to find anyone actually saying it in the modern times.

It can be interpreted as:

> That [thing/story/statement/information] that I have told you is a secret.

---

> That what I have told you is a secret.

This, I would say, is wrong. It sounds either old or uneducated. Some might use "that which" but not "that what".

---

> That I have told you is a secret.

This is perfectly grammatical but it doesn't mean what you want it to mean. This sentence means

> [The fact] that I have told you is a secret.

The information isn't a secret but it is a secret that you know it.

So, for example, let's say that Person A is planning a surprise party for person B. Person C can see that Person B is upset because their friends seem to have forgotten their birthday so Person C tells Person B about the party but then tells them that they have to pretend not to know about it and act surprised so that Person A isn't disappointed that the surprise party wasn't actually a surprise. So, in this case,

> That Person C told Person B [about the party] is a secret [from person A].

Yes, in this case the party is also supposed to be a secret but it was the best I could come up with. at the moment.

Comment: That what - is absulety wrong?

Comment: I don't know that anything is "absolutely" wrong in English... there are too many versions of English and too much variation... and people will argue that "if people use it, is it really wrong?" but as a native AmE speaker, I would at least consider the person using it to be uneducated. It still carries the meaning you wish, though.

Comment: Using *what* instead of *that* seems to mostly be a feature of some UK dialects.  For example, there's a play called [*The Play What I Wrote*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Play_What_I_Wrote).  I think it's considered mainly "rural" and "uneducated", though.  I hope one of our UK users can address this more fully!

Comment: @stangdon Yes! That was the same thinking I had.  A country or even cockney dialect.

Answer (score 0):

The OP's sentences:

> That that I have told you is a secret. [not grammatical]
>   That what I have told you is a secret.
>   What I have told you is a secret.
>   That I have told you is a secret.
>   **I mean to say that the thing i said to you is a secret.**

1) What I told you is a secret. The thing (what) I told you is a secret.

2) I have said twice **that** what I told you is a secret. [relative clause]

3) The /that/ can be left out: I have said twice what I told you is a secret.

4) That I have told you this is a secret. Here the /that/ can function like: the fact that I have told you this.

An example of **that that**: I have told you **that that** boy cannot keep a secret.

The first that introduces the relative clause.
The second that is a demonstrative pronoun.

Comment: I disagree. While it's certainly a bit silly and probably a bit out of date, there's nothing wrong with "That that I have told you is a secret."

Comment: /***That that I have told you a secret/ is not the way to  begin a sentence***, as any native speaker would know. In fact, it is gibberish. It does not mean anything. It can only be used IN a clause: ***It is not a secret that that was what I told you***. And if you think you can start a sentence with /that that/ prove it. The first that introduces the relative clause and the second one is a demonstrative pronoun. So, whoever voted this down (there are four votes) are not native English speakers.

Comment: Also, there are no downvotes on this answer, @Lambie ... so I don't know what you're seeing.

Comment: I meant to say four points next to your comment under this answer. Completely unmerited.

Comment: have you ever considered that the comment is upvoted because you're wrong? You ask us to prove that it is correct but you provide no proof that it is incorrect. If you feel so strongly about it as your comments here would seem to imply, show proof in your answer.

Comment: Upvoted because I am wrong?? It just isn't correct. I have been a linguist for over 40 years, not to mention editor, writer, translator and interpreter with a broad reading/listening, etc. culture. And it ain't so. I am not wrong on this point. /That that/ at the beginning of a sentence can't even be understood. It has no referent, either linguistic or in the real world. And, fyi, negatives cannot be proved.

Comment: @Lambie I'm non-native Speaker but I cleary understand **that that** at the beginning of a sentence. Like in **That that you were doing yesterday is inappropriate**.

Comment: @Lambie However, I've read a few articles and found out that you are right. It is indeed older English and mostly uncommon. **What** is prefered. **That which** is absolutely correct too. **That what** is quite uncommon too.

Comment: @SovereignSun It is not about it being older English, it is meaningless. If you start a sentence with /that that/, no one will know what you are referring to! That Shakespeare thing by the Fool is precisely that: He is showing it does not mean anything. You say: "I cleary [sic] understand that that at the beginning of a sentence." I am saying: /that that/ cannot be used at the beginning of a sentence. It is so simple to understand.

Comment: @Lambie https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/That_that_is_is_that_that_is_not_is_not_is_that_it_it_is

Comment: 1) **/What** you say is true/ 2) **/That which** we discussed is true./ [awkward at beginning of a sentence, very rare, except perhaps in some writing, would not be SPOKEN today] 3) That what=dialectal, as in cockney, often seen in the work of Dickens, for instance. 4) That that=never to start a sentence: **What** I am saying is **that which** you did not understand. **That** you did not understand it is not surprising. I had said **that that** was not easy for a non-native to understand. And that is basically the whole scoop here.

Comment: The Wikipedia thing is a translation from Ancient Greek. Are you interested in grammar or grammatical anomalies?? /That that is, is/ is not a written phrase. It is referring to a prior speech utterance in GREEK. The first **that** refers to something spoken by another person. You were asking about stand-alone sentences. Right? If you want to cover every single footnote in English, first it's best to learn the standard forms. Otherwise, you will never understand if there's a there there.

Answer (score 0):

> That that I have told you is a secret.

While this makes sense, it is a bit of a mouthful. The *that I have told you* bit is identifying what *that* actually means.

> That what I have told you is a secret.

I would argue that *what I have told you* requires commas either side. It's expanding on what *that* is, similar to the first sentence, except it's not *crucial* to understanding the sentence. You're simply adding it in to help the listener understand what you're talking about.

> What I have told you is a secret.

This is probably the best out of the four. You're just stating that what you have told him/her is a secret.

> That I have told you is a secret.

I don't *really* understand what this sentence is trying to say. If you were to place commas around *I have told you*, then the *I have told you* part would become an nonessential phrase, and the sentence would make perfect sense without it: That is a secret.

Comment: That that I have told you is a secret=non-grammatical to start a sentence with.