# Meaning and grammaticality of "see that which we have called being and nonbeing are just notions"

Tags: sentence-meaning

> We have to nourish our insight into impermanence every day. If we do, we will live more deeply, we suffer less, and enjoy life much more. Living deeply, we will touch the foundation of reality, nirvana, the world of no-birth and no-death. Touching impermanence deeply, we touch the world beyond permanence and impermanence. We touch the ground of being and **see that which we have called being and nonbeing are just notions.** Nothing is ever lost. Nothing is ever gained. The Second Dharma Seal is nonself. Nothing has a separate existence or a separate self. Everything has to inter-be with everything else.
>
> Excerpt from "*The Heart of the Buddha's Teaching*"

Is the bold phrase grammatically correct? And what does it mean?
Would it be better to replace 'which' with 'what'?

Comment: **That which**  equates to your **what**, so logically another **that** is required, odd as it seems.

Comment: where should "that" go?

Comment: "see that that which we have called being~~ are just notions", is this possible??

Comment: Is my opinion that which should be replaced with what correct?

Comment: "See that _that which we have called being_..." is the only way it makes sense to me. 'That which' _could_ be replaced with 'what' - I wouldn't say it _should_ be.

Comment: I think that this might be a duplicate of [That that vs That what vs What vs That](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/123807/that-that-vs-that-what-vs-what-vs-that)

Comment: No: It's **that which** that can be replaced by "what".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the confusion is over the use of the the word *that*. Broken down, the original sentence is "We see (A) is (B)", which I feel is fine, and "that which" is part of A. If one prefers, it can be constructed as "We see *that* (A) is (B)", but this produces "(see that) (that which)". As commented by Kate, *what* is equivalent to *that which*, making the full reconstruction

> We touch the ground of being and see that what we have called being
> and nonbeing are just notions.

So yes, the original sentence is grammatically correct. *Which* can be replaced with *what* to improve understanding, but the reasoning is more complex.